# Reading ServletOutputStream to String

Tags: java, concurrency, freemarker

I am trying to read the result of FreemarkerView rendering:

```
View view = viewResolver.resolveViewName(viewName, locale);
view.render(model, request, mockResponse);
```

To read the result, I have created `mockResponse`, which encapsulates the HttpServletResponse:

```
public class HttpServletResponseEx extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

    ServletOutputStream outputStream;

    public HttpServletResponseEx(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        super(response);
        outputStream = new ServletOutputStreamEx();
    }

    @Override
    public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() {
        return outputStream;
    }

    @Override
    public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
        return new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
    }
}
```

And also my ServletOutputStream, which builds the String using StringBuilder:

```
public class ServletOutputStreamEx extends ServletOutputStream {

    StringBuilder stringBuilder;

    public ServletOutputStreamEx() {
        this.stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
    } 

    @Override
    public void write(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException {
        stringBuilder.append(new String(b, "UTF-8"));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

With those I am able to easily read the response with method `ServletOutputStreamEx.toString`.

My problem is that the write method is not called in correct order and in the end the final String is **mixed and not in correct order**. This is probably caused by concurrency in Freemarker, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: I am sure that the write methods are called in the correct order by Freemarker during the rendering stage, otherwise it would generate a garble result. Moreover, Freemarker does not get executed concurrently. I think the problem is in your implementation of `ServletOutputStreamEx`. You have not overridden all the write methods and its super's methods. I don't see you call `super.write(int b)`, it will simply do nothing if this method is called.

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is, but if you get like two `String`s resulting of `ServletOutputStreamEx.write()` calls mixed together. using `StringBuffer` instead of `StringBuilder` would fix this -since `StringBuffer` is synchronized-

Comment: I can't agree, StringBuffer is something that should be deprecated (as described in Effective Java, 2nd Edition), and using a StringBuilder is good, because most of the time a single request (and so a single response) is handled with a thread.

Comment: What do you mean by "concurrency in Freemarker"? When FreeMarker is called from multiple threads, each thread will have its own `Environment` object. The `Writer` object where FreeMarker writes the output is part of the `Environment` object, and is supplied by the caller of FreeMarker. So in principle one can give the same `Writer` object to FreeMarker in multiple threads, but I can't imagine why anybody would do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the responses: the `write(int b)` was not implemented, because it is never called. The problem in the end is the byte array, which also contains the previous String. So the String needs to be created as `String(b, off, len, "UTF-8")`.