# Execute jsp in Spring controller and get response html

Tags: java, spring

How can I execute a JSP in controller and get html response in Sring variable without using `HtmlServletRequestWrapper`

following is my code, i am trying to hit jsp get response html str and pass that html string to itext to generate pdf.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dosomething", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void dosomething(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  throws IOException {
    // setup your Cookie here
    response.setCookie(cookie)
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/account_summary.jsp").include(request, response)

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: It would be better if you explain your functional requirement

Comment: am trying to hit jsp get response html str and pass that html string to itext to generate pdf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit:

I ended up writing this bean (using `HtmlServlet*Response*Wrapper` :-)), I hope it could be useful for someone 
(thanks to: [Reading ServletOutputStream to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656295/reading-servletoutputstream-to-string))

(The viewResolver is autowired so it needs to be defined inside the the servlet context)

```
import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.View;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;

public class InternalRenderer {

    private final static String ENCODE = "UTF-8";

    @Autowired
    private ViewResolver viewResolver;

    public String evalView(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model, Locale locale, String viewName) throws Exception {

        CustomHttpServletResponse customResponse = new CustomHttpServletResponse(response);

        View view = viewResolver.resolveViewName(viewName, locale);

        if(view != null){

            view.render(fillModelMap(model), request, customResponse);

            OutputStream os = customResponse.getOutputStream();

            return os.toString();

        }

        throw new Exception("no view found");
    }

    private Map<String, Object> fillModelMap(Model model) {

        if(model == null)
            return new HashMap<String,Object>();

        return model.asMap();
    }

    class CustomServletOutPutStream extends ServletOutputStream {

        private StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void write(int b) {
            stringBuilder.append(b);
        }

        @Override
        public void write(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException {
            stringBuilder.append(new String(b, off, len, ENCODE));
        }
    }

    class CustomHttpServletResponse extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

        private ServletOutputStream outputStream;
        private PrintWriter printWriter;

        public CustomHttpServletResponse(HttpServletResponse response) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
            super(response);

            this.outputStream = new CustomServletOutPutStream();
            this.printWriter = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, ENCODE));

        }

        @Override
        public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() {
            return this.outputStream;
        }

        @Override
        public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
            return this.printWriter;
        }
    }

}
```

and you can call it like

```
    @Autowired
    InternalRenderer internalRenderer;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/internalRender")
    public void internalRender(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model, Locale locale) throws Exception {

        String evalView = internalRenderer.evalView(request, response, model, locale, "index");

        logger.debug("evalView: " + evalView);

        //TODO: use the generated code to create the pdf and return it

    }
```

---

old response:

You could call /doSomething, getting back the generated html and pass it to another controller as a parameter to make it create the pdf and get it back as a final result (if it is strictly necessary generate the pdf from the html, maybe it's better to generate the pdf using the raw data)

1. call /doSomething (using ajax?)
2. get the generated html back
3. call /createPdf passing the generated html as a paramter
4. get the generated pdf back

Comment: You could also make a call to the server in loopback using an http client, getting back the html, generate the pdf and returns the pdf directly, only one call, a very clean approach :D

Comment: i agree this is work around i tried and it is working well, but actually it is internal call i was looking for some thing i don't have to make httpclient or multiple ajax calls.

Comment: I appreciate you put efforts to write this code, but if you wants to use wrapper it is so wassy using this ways http://www.javascriptdownload.net/site/page.asp?dsy_id=468

Comment: So, the logic is the same but the work should be done inside a custom filter?.

Answer (score -1):

I found a simpler way

1 just add dependency

testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-mock', version: '2.0.8'

2 and then use

```
View resolvedView = this.viewResolver.resolveViewName("viewname", locale);
MockHttpServletResponse mockResp = new MockHttpServletResponse();
resolvedView.render(model, request, mockResp);
System.out.println("rendered html : " + mockResp.getContentAsString());
```

Comment: Your solution only works for unit tests (the `testCompile` group), and the OP indicated this is for runtime.