# How to print ServletOutputStream as string?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlets, httpresponse

@Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)throws Exception {

```
    if (response != null)
    {

        if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) 
        {   

            ServletOutputStream responseOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();

            // How to print or log this responseOutputStream??

            LOGGER.debug("[Response_Body]: " + ??); 
        }
```

Comment: I think you need to refer this issue. [Reading ServletOutputStream to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656295/reading-servletoutputstream-to-string)

Comment: if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) 
   {
    InputStream requestInputStream = wrappedRequest.getRequest().getInputStream();  

    InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(requestInputStream);

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isReader);

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    
    String str;

    while((str = reader.readLine())!= null)
    {
     sb.append(str);
    }
    LOGGER.debug("[Request_Body]: " + sb.toString());

Comment: I am able to parse the request body by this logic..